# Schedule a task apscheduler for every hour and wait if task is not complete

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, apscheduler

I'm trying to schedule a task to run every hour. The task is a function that will take longer and longer execute. The minimum break the function needs is an hour from its **start**.

Once the function starts the one hour clock should be started for it to start again. With that comes a problem. Being that the function gets longer and longer to complete it could take over an hour to complete that function. This means the scheduler would have called the function before it completes. The goal is to start that function every hour from when it began but to wait for it to complete once its starts to take over an hour to run.

This is what iv'e been trying:

```
from threading import Thread
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import threading
import time

def job():
    # This is a function that takes longer
    # and longer
    # and longer
    # to complete

thread = Thread(target = job)
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', hours=1)

if thread.is_alive():
    print("waiting")
else:
    scheduler.start()
```